# Should you strip data down to the most basic type, or is it ok to pass control-related objects via MVC?

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

I'm pretty new to the MVC pattern; I understand it on a most basic level and I'm trying to get better with it.

That said, I have a form with a DataGridView with a single Column ("path") on it and a button that will try to start a process based on the contents of my grid.

I was unsure if my View should send my DataGridViewRowCollection to the Controller, or if I should strip out **just** the text values from my single column and pass that to the controller?

Basically, should it be this:

```
    private void Launch()
    {
        _controller.Launch(dataGridView.Rows);
    }

    public void Launch(DataGridRowCollection rows)
    {
        //iterate over collection
        //process.start(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
    }
```

Or would this be more appropriate:

```
    private void Launch()
    {
        List<string> process = new List<string();
        //iterate over collection
        //add cell value to List
        //pass List to Controller
    }

    public void Launch(List<string> processes)
    {
        //iterate over collection
        //process.start(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
    }
```

I'm conflicted because I want to remove as much work as possible from the View (the former), but to my understanding the Controller should absolutely not interact with any UI elements (the latter).

I hope there is an actual 'Best Practice' and this isn't too much a question of preference

Comment: So you want to implement MVC pattern within the ASP.NET WebForms application?

Comment: @bejger I didn't think that was relevant, but no, this is a winforms application for a tiny little pet project I'm doing. Added winforms tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing view specific infrastructure classes to controllers is against the architecture. One of the major points is that you would like to test controllers without views. And in the approach where you require view specific classes, this could be tricky if not impossible.

Pass simple types or compound types consisting of simple types. The latter version is more appropriate.